# json_encode issue with file_get_contents

Tags: php, json

I have a .json file with this content:

```
{ "questions": "reponse" }
```

And I would like parse the content of the file into a PHP array but I have a strange issue...

```
$path = 'myFile.json';
echo file_get_contents($path); 
echo var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true));
echo var_dump(json_decode(utf8_encode(file_get_contents($path), true)));
$json = '{ "questions": "reponse" }';
echo var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```

And the result on my screen is:

```
{ "questions": "reponse" }
null
null
array (size=1)
  'questions' => string 'reponse' (length=7)
```

What's the difference between the string from the file and the string in my program?

Thank you!

Comment: Trailing whitespace in the file? BOM in the file? What does `strcmp(file_get_contents($path), $json)` show? Also, what does `var_dump(unpack('H*', file_get_contents($path)))` show - this should produce a raw hex dump of your file contents, compare that to the dump of `$json` to see where the difference is.

Comment: Even with trailing whitespace, this parses correctly for me.

Comment: what version of PHP are you using? Maybe this is the solution: `echo file_get_contents($path, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);` Make sure that the path to the file is correct

Comment: The problem shouldn't be the white spaces, the code you just posted works perfectly for me. Are you sure you are reading from a .json file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try run this code:

```
var_dump(json_decode(trim(file_get_contents($path)), true));
```

I expect that there are some whitespaces (like a BOM/UTF-8 header) which make trouble.

Comment: Indeed... it was a BOM/UTF-8 Header! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

`utf8_encode()` takes just one parameter. You pass two. Once it is fixed it shall work:

```
{ "questions": "reponse" }
array(1) {
  ["questions"]=>
  string(7) "reponse"
}
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["questions"]=>
  string(7) "reponse"
}
array(1) {
  ["questions"]=>
  string(7) "reponse"
}
```

Comment: BUt the OP gets a `null` in the test without utf8_encode() as well

Comment: It works for me on his data after that fix, so I suspect his "myFile.json" is where the culprit is. BOM can be the thing to look for